# How can a person get the power of going anywhere at will like the Rishis?

Tags: yoga, shakti, siddhi

Rishis could go anywhere at will like Vyasa.

> And Krishna-Dwaipayana, when he met his mother as before, informed her as to how he had been deceived by the seniormost of the princesses and how he had begotten a son upon a Sudra woman. And having spoken thus unto his mother the **Rishi disappeared from her sight.**

How can a person get the power of going wherever at will?

Comment: Are you asking about the procedure to obtain the powers, or the reason as to why they have such powers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such powers are called Yogic Siddhis (occult powers). A highly adept Yogi, by severe practice of Yoga, can achieve those powers.

> 52. The mighty Yogi having attained, through pranayama, tho eight sorts of psychic powers, and having crossed the ocean of virtue and
>     vice, moves about freely through the three worlds.
> 53. Then gradually lie should make himself able to practise for three ghatis (one hour and a half at a time, he should be able to restrain
>     breath for that period). Through this, the Yogi undoubtedly obtains
>     all the longed-for powers.
> 54. The Yogi acquires the following powers :—vakya siddhi (prophecy), **transporting himself everywhere at will (Kamachari)**,
>     clairvoyance (duradristhi), clairaudience (durashruti), subtle-sight
>     (shukshma-drishti), and the power of entering another’s body
>     (parakaypravesana), turning base metals to gold by rubbing them with
>     his excrements and urine, and the
>     **power of becoming invisible**, and lastly, moving in the air.
>
> **From [Shiva Samhita's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Samhita) Chapter 3**

So, becoming invisible, going anywhere at will etc. are all Yogic powers obtained by severe practice of Yoga, Pranayama under the guidance of a Guru.